# how to change css dynamically through Java script

Tags: javascript, css

I  am having global css file contains below code

```
#menu_left
 {
  color: #004080;
  width: 225px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-style: solid solid none solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-size: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
 }

#menu_left li a
{
 color: #222222;
 height: 26px;
 voice-family: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
 background-color:#D3D7D9;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family:tahoma;
}

#menu_left li a:link, #menu_left li a:visited
{
 color: #222222;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 0 0 10px;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
 background-color:#D3D7D9;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family:tahoma;
}
#menu_left li a:hover
{
 color: #222222;
 padding: 8px 0 0 10px;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
 font-weight:normal;
 background-color:#B9C4CA;
 font-size:12px;
 font-family:tahoma;
}
```

as of now i assigned #menuleft id to my div which contains li's(list tag) and each li tag having one anchor tag.
all my li's will come in the left side panel as list .once i selected any li it should display some css styles and other should have the above css.

i have written one js function to toggle these css changes on selection and un slection .

but hover css is not applying if do like below ...

```
function setSelected(selID)//selId is ID for anchor tag in selected li item
{
 //contains all list of anchor tag id's
  var anchorID=['usersAnchor','securityAnchor','passPolAnchor','activeSessAnchor'];
  for(i=0;i<anchorID.length;i++)
   {
     if(selID!=anchorID[i])
     {
        var div = document.getElementById(anchorID[i]);
        div.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        div.setAttribute('style','color: #222222;height: 26px;voice-family: inherit;text-decoration: none;border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;background-color:#D3D7D9;font-size:12px;font-family:tahoma;');
        }
     else

     {
         var div = document.getElementById(selID);
         div.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
         div.setAttribute('style','color: #FFFFFF; display: block;  padding: 8px 0 0 10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff; background-color:#718296;  font-size:12px;  font-family:tahoma;');
        }
   }
```

can any one help me how can i get  all css properties in such way that it should work for selection hover and normal  while toggeling selection?

Regards,
Kamesh

Comment: `border-size` is not a valid CSS property. Second, you don't need to repeat the `background-color`, `color`, `font-size`, and `font-family` properties for the `a:link`, `a:visited` and `a:hover` selectors (they are inherited from the `#menu_link li a` selector automatically… you will only need to specify them if you are overriding the earlier values). Also, don't specify the `:link` and `:visited` properties as being the same… just make them part of the base `A` tag styles.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use jQuery to make your work simpler!

Instead of using this:

```
div.setAttribute('style','color: #FFFFFF; display: block;  padding: 8px 0 0 10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff; background-color:#718296;  font-size:12px;  font-family:tahoma;');
```

When you use jQuery, it will be easy and cross browser compatible. You can do the same using this way:

```
$('div').attr('style','color: #FFFFFF; display: block;  padding: 8px 0 0 10px; border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff; background-color:#718296;  font-size:12px;  font-family:tahoma;');
```

Or

```
$('div').css({
    'color': '#FFFFFF', 
    'display': 'block', 
    'padding': '8px 0 0 10px', 
    'border-bottom': 'solid 1px #ffffff', 
    'background-color': '#718296', 
    'font-size': '12px', 
    'font-family': 'tahoma'
});
```

The [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) attribute from jQuery can be used! :)

Comment: thanks for response Praveen, cant i make use of my css ID(#menu left) here.if yes can u guide me how can i make use of the above css id which is already i am having it

Comment: The `setAttribute` which you have used, is supported only in Firefox. So, do you use this code only for Firefox users? Let me know. But no problem. I can guide you. Let me know the full code and what you are trying to achieve, as there are better ways to do this! :)

Comment: No i need to support all FF ,IE and chrome. here is my question... if i ma not applying css through js all my css works fine for hover and all you can see above  all my css properties for #menuleft ID.there i dont have a css for selected item (only i written for "#menu_left li a","#menu_left li a:link, #menu_left li a:visited","#menu_left li a:hover") ,so in above setSelected function i have given css for selected item through setAttribute(). but if toggle like this hover is not working.

Comment: @kamesh I understand your point. But the `setAttribute` function works only in Firefox and not in other browsers. Not even in Chrome. Are you aware of that? I just gave an alternate to the JavaScript, which you are using.

Comment: thanks praveen, really i am not aware on this ,i haven't tested yet in chrome and IE.are you talking baout j query stuff ,i dont see any alternative code from you here other than jquery stuff.

Comment: My best suggestion would be, since you are a beginner, use jQuery! :)

Comment: Mark answer if you feel it helped you. Thanks. And you can contact me anytime regarding this, and my contact details are in my profile! :)

Comment: Even though jQuery makes your business code simpler it adds a lot of bloat for simple things like changing a style property. It also doesn't solve the underlying problem, learning and _understanding_ JavaScript and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In your `setSelected` you are overwriting the bold style right after you set it.
That said, you can deal with css a lot more comfortably.

Instead of setting the css right at the node level, why not use what css was invented for?

You can set a a `selected` class and in your code just toggle the `className`

```
.selected {
   color: #222222;
   height: 26px;
   voice-family: inherit;
   text-decoration: none;
   border-bottom: solid 1px #ffffff;
   background-color:#D3D7D9;
   font-size:12px;
   font-family:tahoma;
}
```

And a simple JS function takes care of the class swapping:

```
function setSelected(selID) {
   var anchorIDs = {
       'usersAnchor': true
       'securityAnchor': true
       'passPolAnchor': true
       'activeSessAnchor': true
   };
   var div = document.getElementById(selID),
   className = div.className;

   if (anchorIDs[selID] === true) {
       div.className = className.replace(/\s+(selected)/, " selected");
   } else {
       div.className = className.replace(/\s+(selected)/, "");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`.css` from jQuery API.](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WMEdN/). Is this the effect you are going for? It uses jQuery to make the Javascript easier, but switches the styles by toggling a CSS class instead using jQuery's `.css()` method. There are two reasons for this… The first is that you should separate your code by purpose. HTML should be content, CSS should be styles, and Javascript should be used for logic *only* (you shouldn't put content or styles in your Javascript if possible). The second reason is that it's much easier to use Javascript to switch a class than to switch styles.